# My labtop dose not recognize the usb bootable flash to install Ubuntu 15.10 amd64

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I have an 'Eee PC Asus' and I want to install Ubuntu. I changed the BIOS setting to boot from removable disk, made different software to create boot-able USB (USB works on other laptop) but it does not recognize the USB.
At last I get <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and it shows me this message:

```
Boot block compatible version ver .017
Please do not insert .....
EZ-Flash starting BIOS update 
...
Ckecking for USB Device ..
USB Device found.
Reading file "1015PE.ROM"
```

And still waiting for half an hour.

Should I still wait or something else.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found a video that shows the asnwer.[here](https://craftedflash.com/howto-video/how-boot-asus-eee-pc-netbook-usb-flash-drive)

simple, just press the esc key repeatedly after starting the system to show the boot choosing menu.